# Ignored retain property in Class method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i've a Class method like this:

```
+(CCScene *) sceneWithMovie:(NSString*)movieName level:(NSString*)levelName hudLevel:(NSString*)hudName
{

    bbsScene* scene = (bbsScene*)[super sceneWithMovie:movieName level:levelName];
    ScenePage* hudLayer = (ScenePage*)scene.layer;

    UTLOG(@"---> %p RETAIN COUNT: %d",hudLayer.hudLoader,[hudLayer.hudLoader retainCount]);

    TouchLevelHelperLoader* loader = [[TouchLevelHelperLoader alloc]initWithContentOfFile:hudName];
    hudLayer.hudLoader = loader;

    UTLOG(@"---> %p RETAIN COUNT: %d",hudLayer.hudLoader,[hudLayer.hudLoader retainCount]);

    [loader release];

    UTLOG(@"---> %p RETAIN COUNT: %d",hudLayer.hudLoader,[hudLayer.hudLoader retainCount]);

    [hudLayer.hudLoader addSpritesToLayer:hudLayer];
    NSInteger sceneNumber = [[[[self class]description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Scene" withString:@""]intValue];
    [hudLayer loadTextPage:sceneNumber fromFile:SCENE_TEXT_FILE];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

The output is:

```
2011-09-22 10:53:28.477 MP NO VID[598:207] ---> 0x0 RETAIN COUNT: 0
2011-09-22 10:53:28.490 MP NO VID[598:207] ---> 0x64af820 RETAIN COUNT: 2
2011-09-22 10:53:28.491 MP NO VID[598:207] ---> 0x64af820 RETAIN COUNT: 2
```

When i release loader the data is lost as if i don't call hudLayer.hudLoader = loader;
Obviously i set:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)TouchLevelHelperLoader* hudLoader;
```

Any ideas? Maybe the class mothod (+) is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by the data? Is the hudLoader itself lost or a property of it? if it's a property is it retained?

Comment: After [loader release] hudLoader point to a dead object. hudLoader is a retained property as you can see by the code.

Answer (score 1):

You **shouldn't rely on the `retainCount` property**.

It is not very reliable because you never know what is done behind the scene.

*For example when using Class Clusters like NSString, there are so many things that are done internally in the NSString class that retainCount can't have a real meaning for you. For some cases like NSTimers & so on, objets are also released by the RunLoop (when scheduled on this runloop) but if you don't know it, it is not trivial...*

Obviously these two examples (class clusters and runloop retention) are not what you are having here, but what I'm saying here is that **the `retainCount` property is not something that you should rely on to check if you have a leak**.

*Moreover, if you have the Garbage Collector activated for your project, `release` is a NO-OP (because that's the GC itself that will manage and release the instance)*

Actually, the use of `retainCount` is prohibited since Xcode4 when you use ARC in your project.

**To check if you have leaks in your code, use the Static Analyser ("Build & Analyse" from Xcode Build menu) and/or Instruments "Leaks" tool.**

Comment: With Static Analyser i've no error...
If i comment [loader release] it's all ok and i've no leak but i don't understand why.
Calling 
[hudLayer.hudLoader retain];
[loader release];
should be fine but it's not, it crash.

Comment: Then make it crash in instruments in zombies on and see the whole retain/release stack.

Comment: I tried to run Instrument Zombie but i get always "Target failed to run" and the app won't start. There is an Instruments log that explain the error? I google it but i've no luck.